# $F(t)$ as an $F[t]$-algebra and the Weak Nullstellensatz

Tags: commutative-algebra, extension-field

*Sorry if this question has already been answered somewhere, but it's quite hard to find if so, because of the use of the word 'algebra' in the question...*

1. In the lead up to a proof of the Weak Nullstellensatz ($E/F$ field extension, $E$ finitely-generated as an $F$-algebra, then $E/F$ finite) there is an alternative proof-sketch given as a sidenote:

   > $F(t)$ is not finitely generated as an $F[t]$-algebra (where $t$ is an
   >   independent indeterminate), and so if $F(x)$ *is* a finitely-generated
   >   $F[x]$-algebra, then $F[x]\not\cong F[t]$, and so $x$ is algebraic.

   The thing that I am struggling to understand is how $F(t)$ is not finitely generated as an $F[t]$-algebra: isn't $F(t)$ simply $F[t][t^{-1}]$?
2. Assuming that 1. is understood, how can we use this in an inductive proof of the Weak Nullstellensatz? That is, how can we show that $F(x_1)$ is a finitely-generated $F[x_1]$-algebra? *(i.e. we have just used the induction hypothesis to show that $[E=F[x_1,\ldots,x_m]:F(x_1)]$ is finite, and now need to show the same for $[F(x_1):F]$)*
3. <strike>In the main proof given, which works by induction on the size of the generating set, there is a part which says that</strike>

   > $E=F(x_1)[x_2,\ldots,x_m]$ is finitely generated as an $F(x_1)$-module.

   I understand that the induction hypothesis is used to tell us that $[E:F(x_1)]$ is finite, but don't see how we can use this to show that it is finitely generated as an $F(x_1)$-module.

   **Edit:** Obviously $(E:F(x_1))$ being finite is just saying that it is finitely generated as an $F(x_1)$-module (here module = vector space).

It's very likely that I've just missed something very obvious, but I'm still struggling to get to grips with commutative algebra, so any help would be much appreciated!
If a longer excerpt of the whole proof is needed then let me know. It seems that this is a pretty well-known proof, so I assumed that people might know the gist of it anyway, but I could be wrong!

Comment: For (1), an analogous question to get you unstuck : "is $\mathbf{Q}$ finited generated as a $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra (!) ?

Comment: @knsam No, because we would need to have all the inverses of all the prime numbers in the generating set?

Comment: Yes! So, can you generalise? Do you see that $F[t]$ must have infinitely many irreducible (= prime) elements and you'd need to invert them all, informally!

Comment: Also, the notation $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is used to denote the ring of Laurent polynomials and is certainly different from $F(t)$! For one, things like $1/(t +1) \in F(t)$ don't live in your $F[t, t^{-1}]$.

Comment: @knsam I am drawing a complete blank when it comes to showing that $F[t]$ must have infinitely many irreducible elements when $F$ is just a general field... any hints? Ah yes, of course, $1/(t+1)$ is a great example showing the difference, thank you!

Comment: For the infinitude of primes in $F[t]$: The usual Euclidean proof works since $F[t]$ is a unique factorisation domain!

Comment: @knsam So just like your example, $a+x\in F[t]$ is irreducible for all $a\in F$, and so $F[t]$ has infinitely many primes (since PID means that irreducibles are prime) that would need inverting?

Comment: your proof will need that $F$ is infinite. But recall Euclid's proof: if $F$ is a finite set of primes in $F[t]$, then, by unique factorisation in $F[t]$, the element $1 + \prod_{f \in F} f \in F[t]$ must have prime in its factorisation distinct from those in $F$. Thus, no finite set of primes in $F[t]$ is exhaustive!

Comment: @knsam Of course! I keep on forgetting that we could be working over finite fields in commutative algebra, since so much of the emphasis (in my course) is on applications to algebraic geometry, with $F$ algebraically closed. Any thoughts on the question 2? (I have edited my question slightly). Please feel free to put any of the above in an answer as well so I can accept it!

Comment: Glad that they were helpful! For your 2., by what you quoted in 1., we have that $x_1$ is algebraic over $F$ so $[F(x_1): F]$ is finite (and equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ over $F$).  I will put these in an answer :-)

Comment: (+1 for your question and for patiently working through hints!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a collection of hints from my comments to OP:

- For (1), think about the analogous question: "is $\mathbf{Q}$ finited generated as a $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra (!)?"

> A more explicit answer to (1): Recall that $F[t]$ is a principal ideal domain (much like $\mathbf{Z}$). We will show that $F[t]$ has infinitely many primes.
>
> > If $K$ is a finite set of primes in $F[t]$, then, by unique factorisation in $F[t]$, the element $1+\prod_{\pi \in K}  \pi \in F[t]$ must have prime in its factorisation distinct from those in $K$. Thus, no finite set of primes in $F[t]$ is exhaustive!
>
> Now any set of generators for $F(t)$ as $F[t]$-algebra must contain all these primes by the unique factorisation in $F[t]$. This finishes the proof.

- For (2), it suffices to note that $x_1$ is algebraic over $F$, for then, we have that $[F(x_1): F]$ is finite (and equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ over $F$). But you explain in that in the blockquote in (1).

Comment: thank you for all the hints!